# How to interupt a thread blocked by some socket IO operation without closing it

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io, stream

I am really wondered how to interrupt a thread which is blocked by some I/O operation? The I/O is through a socket, and I do not want to `close()` the socket.

I tried using `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt the thread, but without success.

Thread blocked by IO operation:

```
void run(){
    byte[] data=new byte[1024];
    in.read(data);//blocked!
}
```

Thread to interrupt the blocked thread (did not work):

```
void run(){
    blockedThread.interrupt();//no success!
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot even stop it while you don't have access to underlying stream to close.

Comment: AFAIK it will only work if the blocking operation is interruptable

Comment: @MadProgrammer is interruptable kind of interface? or low-level implementation?!

Comment: @parsaporahmad No, it's a concept. What needs to happen is that what ever action is blocking the thread needs to be monitoring the interrupted state of that thread for it to be interruptable

Comment: Calling Socket.close() on the socket will close the associated InputStream and OutputStream objects and operations on the socket itself will throw a SocketException.

Comment: @MadProgrammer but I don't want to close the stream, I just want to cancel the read operation and keep the stream open.

Comment: @parsaporahmad The problem is, the implementation of the stream needs to provide this functionality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a shortish read timeout on the socket and loop while you get `SocketTimeoutException`, checking `Thread.isInterrupted()` each time. Use `Thread.interrupt()` to interrupt the thread.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely can't/don't want to close the socket using the normal java `Socket` class, you can use a [java.nio.SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) to work with the socket.

`SocketChannel` implements [InterruptibleChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) which can be closed by interrupting the thread that waits on I/O on the socket. In this case the blocked read will throw a [ClosedByInterruptException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html)

Comment: thanks, helped to much, but it's just like closing the socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method like this as any blocking IO operation will throw an IOException:-

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    this.socket.close();
}
```

From the javadoc:-

> Closes this socket. Any thread currently blocked in accept() will
>   throw a SocketException.

Comment: NO! I don't want to close the stream, I want to cancel the current read operation and keep the stream open.

Comment: But how can you keep the socket open if the read could be in the middle of consuming bytes @parsaporahmad?

Comment: I am not saying closing the socket, I want to keep alive the socket but give up the reading for now.

Comment: @parsaporahmad - it sounds like you want to set a read timeout on the socket instead.

Comment: @jtahlborn something like that

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the sun java impl on most platforms does not handle io interruption via thread interrupt (i believe you can get this with some of the nio stuff, unsure).  however, i believe if the thread is blocked reading from a socket, and you have a handle to that socket, you *can* asynchronously close the socket from another thread (which will interrupt the blocked thread).

Comment: would you please give some example/link about nio? I am trying to read data from web/file and I would to interrupt the reading thread.

Comment: @parsaporahmad - most of the nio channel implementations extend http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractInterruptibleChannel.html .

Answer (score 1):

Note how there is no `InterruptedException` declared to be thrown:

> read
>
> ```
> public int read(byte[] b)
>          throws IOException
> ```
>
> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Some read methods will respond to an external interrupt via `Thread#interrupt()`, either closing the stream or throwing an exception.

You can't *otherwise* stop this thread without somehow closing or feeding the stream from another thread, or by killing the thread with `Thread#stop()`. This last method is only a last resort and shouldn't be used for assorted reasons.

Comment: so this is going to good to feed the stream by another thread, and I don't know is it possible?

Comment: There are NIO channels that are interruptible.

Answer (score 1):

I/O like the operations that are waiting for any monitor are not interruptible that is the reason that the `InterruptedException` rutine is not needed by those cases, but according to `Java 7 Documentation`  the I/O classes that belong to `nio` package can respond to any attempt to be interruted throwing one of the stream Interruption exception one of this is [`ClosedByInterruptionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html) and it parent class [`AsynchronousCloseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousCloseException.html).

But in case that you want to close the excution thead, instead of closing the stream, you could consider make use of [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) that provide the way to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/06/05/io-vs-nio-interruptions-timeouts-and-buffers/), especially *Solution 4 – NIO with Buffering*.

In short: For **regular files** you have to use `NIO`, use a `Channel` that extends `AbstractInterruptableChannel`, eg. `FileChannel`.

When using **sockets** use `Socket#close()` to interrupt/close.

According to the javadocs:

> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will
>   throw a SocketException.

**BUT:**

There is another way around the problem: use asynchronous IO with `NIO`, take a look at [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-nio/section3.html). 
The problem with asynchronous IO is, that it is really complex to handle(compared to blocking IO), since you will not relay on streams anymore, but buffers.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to close the stream while I don't want to do. I do not want to close the stream, but I want to cancel teh current read operation.

Comment: There is no way to do that(with blocking operations). If you really have to, i suggest you to use `NIO` asynchronously.

Comment: Well I don't see any BIG difference between NIO and IO here, because both of the will cause to close the socket, except in IO thread closes the socket, while in NIO the class does it so.

Comment: When using asynchronous IO, you will not have to close the socket. You can always break out of the loop where you `select()`.